# How to decrypt a password in lua?

Tags: password-encryption

I have an encrypted password "$H$9f1gABgoDXyr1P0AT7Wz8qAB3.QNGF" and I want to decrypt it but I really can't understand which encryption they used for this password. I took this password from my website forum mysql database. Can anyone tell me how to decrypt this and also tell me the name of this encryption? I've been searching for this since 1 hour and found nothing useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, by design.

The "encrypted password" you've posted is one-way encrypted using a [trapdoor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapdoor_function): the only way to get the original password is to *enter* the original password and see it produce the same output.

If you could "decrypt" this password, there'd be nothing stopping an attacker, after breaking into your password database, from doing the same.

Comment: Suppose I have a string "abc123" now I want to compare it with this encrypted password and I want to check whether they match or not so how would I do this? I'll need to encrypt string "abc123" ? if yes then how?